# Does Active Model Serializers work with JSONP?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, active-model-serializers

If not, how can I make it so that it is JSONP-compliant with my AJAX requests?

**EDIT:** It looks like I am not clear with what I want to achieve. Let's say for example that I have a Post class that contains attributes like id, author, tags and content. Now the following ActiveModel::Serializer is what I would use to code JSON response:

```
class PostSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :author, :tags, :content,
end
```

Now in the controller, I would have do something like

```
render :json => @post
```

to generate a JSON file that looks like this

```
{
  "posts": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "author": "John Doe",
      "tags": "test",
      "content": "Hello world"
    }
  ]
}
```

Now my objective here is to use JSONP, so that when someone passes in a jsoncallback parameter in the request (e.g. GET '/posts?jsoncallback=callback_function'), I would be able to generate the following:

```
callback_function({
  "posts": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "author": "John Doe",
      "tags": "test",
      "content": "Hello world"
    }
  ]
})
```

Currently I am using to_json on a Post object and storing the result into a variable called @posts_json, then specifying the Content-Type as text/javascript in the controller, and rendering out an html.erb file that looks like the following:

```
<% if params[:jsoncallback].blank? %>
<%= @posts_json.html_safe %>
<% else %>
<%= params[:jsoncallback] %>(<%= @posts_json.html_safe %>)
<% end %>
```

I'm sure you'll agree that this solution is really ugly, and the issue is that it is starting to give me problems due to the to_json method that I am using in the controller.

As such, I would like to use ActiveModel::Serializer to obtain the same functionality. How might I do that?

Comment: Let us see some code...

Comment: @Severin Done... I was hoping that AMS has an option where I could do something like `render json: @post, jsonp: callback_function`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So apparently in plain Rails, the `render` syntax already handles the callbacks. Simply pass in callback: params[:jsoncallback] as an option would do the trick.

Click [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/render) and browse under the **Rendering JSON** section for the documentation.